# Variable scope in for c++

Tags: c++

Consider this:

```
for (int iii=0; iii < 10; iii++)
    cout << iii << " ";
```

Why doesn't iii lose it's value after the first for iteration?

Comment: Do you mean the first for-statement or the first pass of that for-loop?

Comment: lose value where? and what do mean by  `after the first for` ?

Comment: why would it lose it?

Comment: the world would come to a standstill(infinite loop) if it did..

Comment: I mean for the first iteration. You can't use the variable after this for, but it keeps it's value through the whole for. I mean the program prints 0,1,2... and not 0,0,0,0 which would do if iii would be initialized at each for step

Comment: Because it is defined that way so that people can write for-loops that actually loop correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the following `for`

```
for (initialization ; condition ; increment)
{
    body;
}
```

is equivalent to the following `while`

```
{
    initialization;
    while (condition)
    {
        body;
        increment;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this is the answer I was looking for. Although you can't see that the initialization is done like that when looking at the for.

Answer (score 3):

Because scope of variables defined in `for` loop is body of that `for` statement.

In your case, `iii` is visible inside `for` loop, but not outside of it.

Comment: So it's something like {int i;  for(i=0;...)} ?

Answer (score 3):

Because this is equivalent to:

```
{
    int iii = 0;
    while(iii < 10){
        cout << iii << " ";
        iii++;
    }
}
```